# Can I toggle Alt + Tab's functionality?

Tags: windows-10

I've been wondering if there is such thing as an <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> toggle for when one is playing a game.

So here's the concept I'm after:

A toggle like <kbd>F9</kbd> to disable and enable <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> so one doesn't accidently <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the game/program (Valorant in my case).

Comment: Likely an AutoHotKey script could do it. But, the downside would be, if you disable those keys, what if in game things are bound to Alt and Tab?

Comment: Some gaming keyboards have a "game mode", which blocks certain keys like the Windows key. Maybe there's a keyboard with a similar mode that can specifically block Alt+Tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). The script in question would be:

```
!Tab::
return
```

to disable the key, or to rebind it something like (rebinding to <kbd>F8</kbd>):

```
!Tab::F8
```

Use <kbd>F9</kbd> to toggle on <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
IsEnabled := 1
F9::
if (IsEnabled = 1) {
    IsEnabled := 0
} else if(IsEnabled = 0) {
 IsEnabled := 1
}
return
#If IsEnabled
!Tab::
return
```